# Julia: FAST way of calculating the smallest distances between two sets of points

Tags: performance, julia

I have 5000 3D points in a Matrix `A` and another 5000 3D point in a matrix `B`.

For each point in `A` i want to find the smallest distance to a point in `B`. These distances should be stored in an array with 5000 entries.

So far I have this solution, running in about `0.145342 seconds (23 allocations: 191.079 MiB)`. How can I improve this further?

```
using Distances

A = rand(5000, 3)
B = rand(5000, 3)

mis = @time minimum(Distances.pairwise(SqEuclidean(), A, B, dims=1), dims=2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a standard way to do it as it will have a better time complexity (especially for larger data):

```
using NearestNeighbors
nn(KDTree(B'; leafsize = 10), A')[2] .^ 2
```

Two comments:

- by default Euclidean distance is computed (so I square it)
- by default NearestNeigbors.jl assumes observations are stored in columns (so I need `B'` and `A'` in the solution; if your original data were transposed it would not be needed; the reason why it is designed this way is that Julia uses column major matrix storage)

Comment: Oh, wow, this solution is around 50% faster than the (already FAST) one provided by @Jérôme Richard

Comment: Good. This is indeed an interesting solution for large matrices. It is a bit faster than the basic two nested loops on the OP input. With SIMD/cache optimizations, the 2 loops should be faster. That being said, I guess this solution use only 1 thread and it also have the benefit to be simple.

Comment: You can easily make it multi-threaded by splitting `A` matrix into chunks. However, the real difference would be if these matrices would have like 1 million rows each. Then the kdtree approach takes 1.3 second (without multi-threading) and the other solution would take at least several minutes (a quick estimate on my computer is 30 minutes).

Answer (score 6):

Generating a big distance matrix using `Distances.pairwise(SqEuclidean(), A, B, dims=1)` is not efficient because **the main memory is pretty slow** nowadays compared to CPU caches and the computing power of modern CPUs and this is not gonna be better any time soon (see ["*memory wall*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall)). It is faster to compute the minimum on-the-fly using **two basic nested for loops**. Additionally, one can use multiple cores to compute this faster using **multiple threads**.

```
function computeMinDist(A, B)
    n, m = size(A, 1), size(B, 1)
    result = zeros(n)
    Threads.@threads for i = 1:n
        minSqDist = Inf
        @inbounds for j = 1:m
            dx = A[i,1] - B[j,1]
            dy = A[i,2] - B[j,2]
            dz = A[i,3] - B[j,3]
            sqDist = dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz
            if sqDist < minSqDist
                minSqDist = sqDist
            end
        end
        result[i] = minSqDist
    end
    return result
end

mis = @time computeMinDist(A, B)
```

Note the Julia interpreter uses 1 thread by default but this can be tuned using the environment variable `JULIA_NUM_THREADS=auto` or just by running it using the flag `--threads=auto`. See [the multi-threading documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/multi-threading/) for more information.

---

### Performance results

Here are performance results on my i5-9600KF machine with 6 cores (with two 5000x3 matrices):

```
Initial implementation:  93.4 ms
This implementation:      4.4 ms
```

This implementation is thus **21 times faster**.
Results are the same to few ULP.

Note the code can certainly be optimized further using [loop tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_nest_optimization), and possibly by *transposing* `A` and `B` so the JIT can generate a more efficient implementation using *SIMD instructions*.

Comment: I guess it would be neat to avoid brackets in the `size(A)[1], size(A)[1]` by simply replacing it with `size(A, 1), size(A, 1)`.

Comment: @Shayan Good idea. I did not know this notation. I learn Julia by answering questions like this :) . Thank you.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer can be tweaked further by adding an `@inbounds for j = 1:m ...`

Comment: @Benvorth Indeed, it is nearly twice faster :) ! Thank you too.